# Как сделать полукруговой ProgressBar?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

Нужно реализовать такую штуку. Думал сделать с помощью shape, но пока только круговой получился. Есть способы полукругом сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22499964